# Having problems with the layout widget 'Container' in LibGdx

Tags: user-interface, layout, menu, libgdx

I'm building a menu for my game and I'm stuck.

When I position a [Container](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Container.html) with it's `setPosition` function and add a Button to the container with `setFillParent` set to `true` the button's position isn't set to the same position as the container.

The button size matches the size of the Container but its position is wrong. When I don't set `setFillParent` to `true` the position of the button within the container is right but the size is wrong.

Here is the code, pretty simple:

```
Container container = new Container(exitButton);

exitButton.setFillParent(true/false);
```

[Here is an image that ilustrate this, left image has `setFillParent` set to `true` and the right image does not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4rMO.png)

The green hightlight on the image is the `container`, the [X] image is the `exitButton`.

Comment: I should add, setting the button's size does not work.

Comment: Please include the images in the post.

Comment: @LiranFunaro how can I do this?

Comment: @LiranFunaro It allows me only to make links.

Comment: @Joano On the edit box toolbar there is an icon of an "image".

Comment: @LiranFunaro That Icon allows me only to upload an image and give a link, how can i show the image without people having to click the link?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, calling `container.fill()` before setting the containers size and position somehow solves the problem. No idea why, but it solves it.

Comment: invoking setRound(false) on the layout table can work sometimes too

Comment: The reason `fill()` solves it is that the container is controlling the size of the button in it. By default (when fill is off), it just sizes the button to the button's natural size instead of enlarging it to fit the container. `setFillParent` should not be used by anything except the top level of a widget hierarchy.