# Actor's position is wrong when setFillParent is true, in LibGDX

Tags: java, layout, libgdx, actor, stage

I've been hours trying to solve this and am going nuts, please take a look at my problem.

Image illustrating the problem:

[Image illustrating this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6604n.png)

- When the `exitButton`'s `setFillParent` function is set to `false` the
  results are the right side of the image, the button is centered
  inside the [Container](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Container.html) but the size is wrong.
- When the `exitButton`'s `setFillParent` function is set to `true` the
  results are the left side of the image, the button is sized correctly
  but the position is wrong.

Here's the code:

```
    Container container = new Container(exitButton);

    container.fill();

    container.setRound(false);

    container.setSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);

    exitButton.setFillParent(true);

    //exitButton.setFillParent(false);

    container.setPosition(
            ((float)viewportWidth/7f) - (buttonSize/2f)
            ,((float)viewportHeight*5f/6f)  - (buttonSize/2f)
    );
```

Comment: what's about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958162/having-problems-with-the-layout-widget-container-in-libgdx) question, looking similar

Comment: Use `scale` instead of `resize` also enable transform for container.

Answer (score 0):

Widgets are designed to be sized by their parents. `setFillParent(true)` allows a widget to override this and set its own size (to match its parent's size). You never want to do this unless it's the top level widget of an hierarchy, because when a widget takes control of its own size, it's parent loses the ability to correctly position it.

As for why the button is drawn bigger than the container, that can happen if the `minWidth`/`minHeight` of the child is bigger than the parent. Assuming `exitButton` is an ImageButton or just a Button, this means the drawable for its Image or background is bigger than `buttonSize`.

The easiest way around this is to override `getMinWidth()` and `getMinHeight()` to return zero. For example:

```
exitButton = new Button(skin, style){
    public float getMinWidth(){return 0;}
    public float getMinHeight(){return 0;}
};
```